# GoDaddy Managed Wordpress Hosting + Cloudflare = 429 Crawl Error in Webmaster Tools

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console, cloudflare

Following setup:

- GoDaddy Managed Wordpress Hosting + SSL
- Cloudflare as CDN

Google Webmaster Tools shows all pages with 429 crawl error. I tested manually and with tools like monitor.us and I couldn't find any issues loading any of the pages.

Anyone an idea? 
Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question. [webmasters.se] might be a better place to ask, but check their help centre before you post.

Answer (score 0):

A 429 is not an error CloudFlare generates, so this actually sounds like [rate-limiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#429) on the server.

Do you have something like [mod_cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads) installed to restore the visitor IP? My hunch is that you don't, so all of the requests appear to come from our IPs & this *might* be the cause of the error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do have the CloudFlare Wordpress Plugin installed which is supposed to restore the visitor IP, correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to Cloudflare, the WP plugin does not restore visitor IPs on the server side.  Still need to install mod_cloudflare.